# iTunes and RaspBMC - Airplay version not supported

Tags: macos, kodi

Today I installed RaspBMC on my new Raspberry PI and it works just fine! I connected my iTunes to it using AirPlay - worked well too. I turned the Raspberry PI off in the meanwhile, after booting it back up I wanted to connect my iTunes (Mac OS X 10.9.1) to the RaspBMC using AirPlay but it said the AirPlay version does not support this iTunes version. Now I'm confused since it worked a while ago...

Any ideas where the problem is?

Thanks for your help in advance!